How to search for job postings with location and keyword filters using LinkedIn's API (v2)?
I am working on an integration that requires access to LinkedIn's job search functionalities. Specifically, I need to search for job postings filtered by:
Location (e.g., San Francisco)
Keywords (e.g., Python)
Easy Apply option
I am having difficulty identifying the correct API endpoints and documentation for LinkedIn’s API (v2) that support this functionality. I've already reviewed LinkedIn's Developer website but couldn't find relevant details about the specific filtering options I need.
Could someone please guide me on the following?
Which API endpoint allows job searches with filtering options like location, keywords, and Easy Apply?
Is it part of the "Apply with LinkedIn" API (that requires partnership)?
Any sample requests or documentation links for setting up these filters.
Instructions on obtaining API access and the necessary permissions for this use case.
Thanks in advance!
Note: I’ve tagged this with #linkedin for visibility from LinkedIn engineers as advised by LinkedIn Support.
